# How to use NSSharingServicePicker with an array or URLs?

Tags: swift, macos

I have an array of URLs that I want to pass on to NSSharingServicePicker.  In most cases, they are URLs to image files.

If I pass a single URL to NSSharingServicePicker, it works as expected and shows a list of services to share the item to.  This is the code that works:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    var selectedItems = [fileURL1, fileURL2, fileURL3]
    let item = selectedItems[0]
    let picker = NSSharingServicePicker(items: [item])
    picker.show(relativeTo: .zero, of: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: .maxX)
}
```

However, I want to pass on the entire array like the following but this fails.  For example, I want to pass 3 images to share to an email:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    var selectedItems = [fileURL1, fileURL2, fileURL3]
    let picker = NSSharingServicePicker(items: [selectedItems])
    picker.show(relativeTo: .zero, of: sender as! NSView, preferredEdge: .maxX)
}
```

The error I get trying the above is:

> 2021-05-27 11:48:23.397566-0600 testapp[9664:13409352] [Framework] Object does not conform to NSPasteboardWriting protocol: (
> "file:///Volumes/drivea/My_Files/My_Photos/20191201_180741.jpg",
> "file:///Volumes/drivea/My_Files/My_Photos/IMG_002.HEIC",
> "file:///Volumes/drivea/My_Files/My_Photos/IMG_3097.JPG"
> )

Am I missing something simple here?  How can I pass several URLs to NSSharingServicePicker?
I am struggling with how to make the Object (I assume that refers to an array of URLs??) to conform to NSPasteboardWriting protocol.

Comment: `[selectedItems]` is an array with an array of URLs. Try `NSSharingServicePicker(items: selectedItems)`.